# Text hides underneath image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a simple html page which will show website is under maintenance. There is an image which covers the whole page and a text should be shown at the center of the image. However the text is hidden underneath the image. I guess it is because I am using jQuery to align the image to cover the whole page. I appreciate any comments or sample codes which might help.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    var theWindow = $(window);
    var $bg = $("#bg");
    var aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
    
    function resizeBg() {
        if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio) {
            $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg.removeClass().addClass('bgwidth');
        }
    }
    
    theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.bgwidth {
    width: 100%;
}

.bgheight {
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Page under maintenance</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This website is down.</p>
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="Maintenance View" id="bg">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `z-index` to the `p`.

```
  <p style="position: relative; z-index: 1; font-size: 3em; font-weight: bold;
  color: yellow;">This website is down.</p>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/moq5b9jx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
p { 
    overflow: inherit;

    /* Add these */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Just give it a higher z-index to bring it forward.